# What is the correct way to send the user to set permissions

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, swiftui

What is the correct way to send the user to settings in order to allow permissions if he already dismissed the first default alert of IOS that asked for permissions for the app ?

I am using the following code in order to to send the user to settings and allow notifications permission, this is done in case that the user were to dismiss the first default dialog that asks for permissions directly and is done by IOS.
The app uses Core Data as local data base, the UI established with SwiftUI.

This is the code I am using to send the user to the settings in order to allow permissions:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

But I am getting a purple warning on the following line that is needed (among other things) in order to create a new object in Core Data :

```
  guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
```

The purple warning:

```
UIApplication.delegate must be used from main thread only
```

I am also getting the following purple warning `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`
on published properties that are being published and that I wish to modify on runtime.

And so on.. Problems with handling the Core Data database. It seems clear that the problem is that this first line of code that sends the user to the settings section of the device is causing the app to not run on the main thread like it should, hence the errors.

It doesn't seem right to me to add `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` on any Core Data handling  function, and I am not sure if it will solve all of the problems.

What is the right way to send the user to settings in order to allow permissions if he already dismissed the first default alert of IOS that asked for permissions for the app ?

Answer (score 0):

The purple warnings are coming from Main Thread Checker which is a useful tool in Xcode that helps you find attempts to access things from a wrong queue. Even though you can disable it in your scheme settings, I highly recommend not doing it because it helps you find concurrency issues in your code.

The AppDelegate (and any UI related things) should only be accessed from the main queue and any instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` should be accessed only from the queue it was created on, otherwise you can run into issues like crashes or data corruption.

If you need to send the user to the settings from a queue that is not main, you'll have to dispatch to the main queue.

If you need to do Core Data operations on multiple queues, start by reading the "Concurrency" section on the [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) documentation page.

Comment: I don't need to make Core Data operations in multiple queues, but that's what happening when I am sending the user to the settings. Is it something that suppose to happen ? How can I avoid it rather then changing the Core Data operation ? My only goal is to run on the main thread (or whatever default behavior) but sending the user to settings change this situation.

Comment: @ChesterK2, I see, in this case it's worth looking into how the lines where the Main Thread Checker stops are getting called. Could you please share a bit more code that shows from where you're accessing the AppDelegate when creating a new Core Data object?